# my iPhone was damaged and i need to know how to collect my stuff from icloud

Tags: icloud, iphone

my iPhone was damaged and i need to know how to collect my stuff from ICloud ?
the phone is not responding for anything and i need to collect my stuff from it before sending it to the shop
i had open my account on ICloud but there is nothing shown for sync

Comment: Could you edit this to explain what "I had open my account on iCloud" means. Is that looking at the broken phone, another iOS device or https://icloud.com Secondly, has the iPhone ever connected to iTunes on a PC or Mac? You might get data from there or get one last sync depending on the damage. It's hard to guess with so many important details missing. Also, won't the shop explain how to prepare your iPhone before sending it in? Apple has articles on how to back up your data before sending a phone to service at http://support.apple.com if you care to search for it.

Comment: i meant that i had open my icloud account from a new PC because i forget which laptop i have been used before for backup

Comment: sorry for my English these is not my mother language

Answer (score 1):

Go to iCloud.com. 
Sign in with your Apple ID. 
Click the gear icon labeled Settings.
Scroll to the bottom, where you will find 'Restore my Files","Restore my Contacts", and "Restore my Calendars and Reminders".

Under each of these 'Restore' items, you will see what is saved on iCloud. You can not download it, only Restore this info to your device. So, this way, you can be assured of what is backed up on iCloud. When your iPhone is repaired and returned, you can simply Restore from this iCloud.com or from the phone itself.

If nothing shows, then your iCloud sync unfortunately didn't occur.